# Can time between dates be visually represented in an ongoing way?

Tags: date, google-sheets, sequence, schedule

I am trying to visually represent a schedule for when certain "Containers" will be occupied based on user input dates. I made it part way through a solution using functions before running into the error of the SEQUENCE function not expanding because it would overwrite previous data, before realizing this problem may be trickier than I thought...

The Problem:

Sheet1 has column A,B,C. Col A cells will be a user chosen number between 1-5 representing which container is occupied. Col B is a start date, col C is an end date.
On Sheet2, col A is a running continuous column of days of the month/year down the sheet. I want columns B-F to represent the "containers" from sheet1. In columns B-F I would like to display any kind of character or cell color formatting, filling in the cells from start date to end date, in their respective columns.

For example, if in container 1 there were 10 days from start to end then 10 cells would be occupied in the respective container column on sheet2, in the position of the correct dates. There will never be more than one item occupying the same container at the same time, however there will be successive items in the same container at different times, all would need to be displayed.
I am no expert, but I think what I'm trying to do may not be possible with my skill level, but i'd appreciate any ideas, or input to know whether I should give up!

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: It would be great if you can share the sheet you are working on as well as the script/formula you have done. Please remove sensitive information.